# Pandas Group By + Cumsum on Categorical Variable

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have bets on football matches that users have done. Their status is correct or incorrect. Each week ('jornada' in the table) there are 10 matches per users. Also, the users are grouped into communities.

I want to compute the cumulative ratio `#Corrects / (#Corrects + #Incorrects)` per week ('jornada') foreach user.

This is how the dataset would look like:
[image]

Every week, each user is going to have 10 new guesses ('number'), that have to be accumulated to his previous guesses on the same season ('temporada').

This is what I have tried:

```
bets.groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada'])['status'].cumsum()
```

But is raising the error: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

I am also trying to covert the status using get_dummies and then apply cum_sum on the group, but I should get the same ratio for the 10 times the same user appears in the same week and it is not happening:

```
dum = pd.get_dummies(bets['status'])
bets2 = pd.concat([bets, dum], axis=1) 

corrects = bets2.groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada'])['Correct'].cumsum()
incorrects = bets2.groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada'])['Incorrect'].cumsum()
ratio = corrects / (corrects + incorrects)
bets3 = pd.concat([bets2, ratio], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new para help to calculate

```
s1=bets.assign(correct=bets['status']=='Corrects').groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada']).correct.cumsum()
s2=bets.assign(correct=bets['status']=='Incorrects').groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada']).correct.cumsum()
bets['New']=(s1/(s1+s2)).values
```

Comment: Thanks Wen! This way I am getting a ratio per row but it is not a problem as I can again bets2 = bets.groupby(['temporada', 'username', 'comunidad', 'jornada'])['New'].mean().     

The problem is that the other 4 columns appears as the index of the new dataframe instead of new columns. Do you know why?

Comment: @PabloRuizRuiz adding reset_index() at the end

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much :)